Nestjs serverless in lambda size limit
I have an nest js api running locally then i have decided to deploy it on the aws lambda but there is a limit of 250mb unzipped
then i tried deploying using ecr with docker image container and webpack bundler but none of it works. Is there any other way to rectify this?
